# how to get the all items exist in QlistWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

i have a function that display a list of files exist in selected directory then the user enter a searched word where  the program read these file in the background in order to find the matching word, at the end it override the existing list by just displaying the files that include the matching word.

the problem is it the **while loop** 
the system display this error :

> while index < len(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count()):
>
> builtins.TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

## code:

```
def listFiles(self):

        readedFileList = []
        index = 0
        while index < len(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count()):
            readedFileList.append(self.listWidgetPDFlist.item(index))
        print(readedFileList)

        try:
            for file in readedFileList:

                with open(file) as lstf:
                    filesReaded = lstf.read()
                    print(filesReaded)
                return(filesReaded)

        except Exception as e:
            print("the selected file is not readble because :  {0}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`count()` returns the number of items so it is an integer, the function `len(`) applies only to iterable, not integers, so you get that error, plus it is not necessary. you must do the following:

```
def listFiles(self):
    readedFileList = [self.listWidgetPDFlist.item(i).text() for i in range(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count())]
    try:
        for file in readedFileList:
            with open(file) as lstf:
                filesReaded = lstf.read()
                print(filesReaded)
                # return(filesReaded)

    except Exception as e:
        print("the selected file is not readble because :  {0}".format(e))
```

*Note: do not use return, you will have the loop finish in the first iteration.*

Comment: i tried your answer  so now the function read all the existing files in the **QlistWidget**... thank you   ... what i want is after the user enter the searched word the system override the existing list and display just the files that includes the matching expression....

i will add to the question a second function that make the search if it can be improved this will be great.